# Select unique records from multiple records based on max date

Tags: oracle, group-by, max

I have table like below

```
+----+----------+-----+-------------+--------+
| ID |   ADDR   | IND | update_Date | Sq_NBR |
+----+----------+-----+-------------+--------+
|  1 | PHYSICAL | Y   | 11-Oct      |   1293 |
|  1 | BILL     | Y   | 10-Oct      |   1357 |
|  1 | BILL     | N   | 10-Sep      |  13567 |
|  1 | PHYSICAL | Y   | 10-Oct      |   8403 |
|  1 | BILL     | Y   | 6-Oct       |    135 |
|  2 | PHYSICAL | Y   | 9-Oct       |   5333 |
|  2 | BILL     | N   | 8-Aug       |    657 |
|  2 | BILL     | Y   | 8-Oct       |   3673 |
|  2 | BILL     | Y   | 10-Oct      |   2574 |
|  3 | BILL     | Y   | 11-Oct      |  57923 |
|  3 | BILL     | Y   | 11-Oct      |  29384 |
+----+----------+-----+-------------+--------+
```

need to check below multiple conditions before populating the data

1. If record has a combination of duplicate id, addr and Ind, then select the max(update_date) from that record.
2. If record has a combination of duplicate id, addr, Ind and update_Date, select only one record from the duplicate records (It can be any record).

Below was the expected result.

Can anyone plug me some ideas to achieve this.

here is the sqlfiddle:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d0098/1

```
+----+----------+-----+-------------+--------+
| ID |   ADDR   | IND | Update_Date | Sq_NBR |
+----+----------+-----+-------------+--------+
|  1 | PHYSICAL | Y   | 11-Oct      |   1293 |
|  1 | BILL     | Y   | 10-Oct      |   1357 |
|  1 | BILL     | N   | 10-Sep      |  13567 |
|  2 | PHYSICAL | Y   | 9-Oct       |   5333 |
|  2 | BILL     | N   | 8-Aug       |    657 |
|  2 | BILL     | Y   | 10-Oct      |   2574 |
|  3 | BILL     | Y   | 11-Oct      |  29384 |
+----+----------+-----+-------------+--------+
```

Comment: Calculate `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, addr, ind ORDER BY update_date DESC)` in CTE and select only records where the calculated value is 1.

Comment: I think your description is not clear. Do you want the following: Divide the rows of a table into groups. A group should consist of all rows that have the same ID, ADDR and update_Date. From each group select an arbitrary row whose update_Date is  equal to the maximal update_Date  of its group.

Answer (score 1):

Query below gives me the desired result :

```
SELECT  
       ID,
       ADDR,
       IND,
       UPDATE_DATE,
       SQ_NBR           
FROM (
SELECT ID,
       ADDR,
       IND,
       UPDATE_DATE,
       SQ_NBR,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID , ADDR , IND ORDER BY UPDATE_DATE DESC) RMN
FROM TEST_TABLE ) A
WHERE RMN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first condition

- count() Over (Partition by id, addr, Ind)
- max(update_date) Over (Partition by id, addr, Ind)

For the secontd condition

- row_number Over (Partition by id, addr, Ind and update_Date)

Answer (score 0):

Inner `"group by"` solves the second condition of a question, and outer plus `"max (sq_nbr) keep.."` works for the first condition.

```
HR@mydb> select id, addr, ind, max(update_date),
  2         max (sq_nbr) keep (dense_rank last order by update_date) AS sq_nbr
  3    from
  4  (select id, addr, ind, update_date, min(sq_nbr) sq_nbr
  5    from orgin
  6   group by id, addr, ind, update_date)
  7   group by id, addr, ind
  8   order by id, addr desc
  9  /

    ID ADDR            I MAX(UPDATE_DATE)    SQ_NBR
---------- --------------- - ------------------- ----------
     1 PHYSICAL        Y 11.10.2018 00:00:00 1293
     1 BILL            N 10.09.2018 00:00:00 13567
     1 BILL            Y 10.10.2018 00:00:00 1357
     2 PHYSICAL        Y 19.10.2018 00:00:00 5333
     2 BILL            N 08.08.2018 00:00:00 657
     2 BILL            Y 10.10.2018 00:00:00 2574
     3 BILL            Y 11.10.2018 00:00:00 29384

7 rows selected.
```

The definition of the `First` function - `max() over keep ...` is here
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions065.htm#i1000901

Answer (score 0):

`LAST_VALUE()` comes to mind.  Documentation is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions073.htm).

```sql
select
  last_value(id) over (partition by id,addr,ind order by update_date) as id,
  last_value(addr) over (partition by id,addr,ind order by update_date) as addr,
  last_value(ind) over (partition by id,addr,ind order by update_date) as ind,
  last_value(update_date) over (partition by id,addr,ind order by update_date) as update_date,
  last_value(sq_nbr) over (partition by id,addr,ind order by update_date) as sq_nbr
from orgin
```

But, if you upgrade to a current version of Oracle (12c+), you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` statement. Example is [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/pattern-matching-in-oracle-database-12cr1).

```sql
select a.*
from orgin
  MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
    partition by id,addr,ind
    order by update_date
    measures
      last( anyrow.update_date ) as update_date,
      last( anyrow.sq_nbr) as sq_nbr
    one row per match
    pattern (anyrow+)
    define
      anyrow as 1=1
    ) a;
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest this:

```
select ID, ADDR, IND, Update_Date, Sq_NBR
from yourTable as yt
inner join
    (select max(Update_Date) as newestDate, ID, ADDR, IND
     from yourTable
     group by ID, ADDR, IND
    ) as newTable
on yt.ID = newTable.ID
and yt.ADDR = newTable.ADDR
and yt.IND = newTable.IND
and yt.Update_Date = newTable.newestDate
order by ID, ADDR
```

Comment: no, that is not correct. this may select more than one record per group

Comment: Thanks, I'll work on it with an actual dataset. My GROUP BY clause is probably off here..